# How to call ion-refresher function programatically?

Tags: ionic-framework

trying to call ion-refresher's function programatically by calling the function name: 'doRefresh(refresher)' , it works fine when pull down from the view as the event (refresher) is being passed.

now I would like to trigger doRefresher programatically, which I tried and it works but fails on "refresher.complete()" as the refresher is not passed, How do i pass the refresher?

(home.ts) Do refresher method:

```
doRefresh(refresher?) {

let d = get_data();

 if (d == "d"){
    refresher.complete();
  }else{
    console.log('value is not d')
    refresher.complete()
  }
}
```

(home.ts) ionviewdidload

```
ionViewDidLoad(){
  this.doRefresh();
}
```

html:

```
   <ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event);">
   <ion-refresher-content 
      pullingText="Pull to refresh" pullingIcon="arrow-dropdown" 
      refreshingSpinner="circles"
   refreshingText="..fetching">
   </ion-refresher-content> 
   </ion-refresher>
```

Would like to know how can I pass "refresher" to the doRefresh() method?

Comment: ionRefesh is gesture event. so you can call doRefesh method programatically.

Comment: it works when i do this.doRefresh(), but the loading spinner keeps showing as the refresher.complete() cannot be called because i am not passing "refresher"

Comment: what you mean by refresher not passing

Comment: add spinner and do show / hide as per your requiremnt

Comment: i mean the refresher object passed into the function -> doRefresh(refresher), how can i pass the "refresher" when i call  this.doRefresh(). so that the refresher.complete() can be called

Comment: because right now when i call the this.doRefresh() function programatically, the spinner keeps loading and stays loading forever, because refresher.complete() cannot be called as the "refresher" object is not being passed

Comment: add your own spinner and show/hide

Comment: ok that's the only option right? there's no other predefined way?

Comment: check same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47220564/ionic-show-ion-refresher-programmatically